# Servlet initialization in a container

Tags: servlets

How does a  web container know that a particular servlet hasn't been initialized. Is there any particular flag which shows the status of the servlet or anything else managed by the servlet

Comment: Wether the servlet container knows it or not, it is a matter of the container itself, nothing of the programmer's business. Of corse the container can know perfectly when a servlet is initialized, because every servlet is accessed through a specific ClassLoader, which takes in account every loaded class. Why are you interesed about this?

Comment: Because we know that the container calls the service method only after the servlet in initialized. So how's the implementation that it know the status?

Comment: I suppose because the logic of the implementation itself gurantees this sequence: First it invokes servlet.init(), and then servlet.service(). But I insist: If the webserver is JEE compliant, it *must* gurantee that the servlet is initialized before using it. How it does it, it is a matter private to that implementation. We programmers should not care about it.

Comment: But it is YOU who need to know about the state of any servlet, better follow @AlirezaFattahi's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Container initial servlet  during start up ( or restart ) one by one as mentioned in web.xml. You can also find if a servelt is initiated or destroyed by override `init` and `destroy` methods.

```
public class PrecompressedResourceServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(PrecompressedResourceServlet.class);

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        LOG.info("The PrecompressedResourceServlet initialized...");
        super.init();
    }
}
```